# Load and print file using Struct - with Programing C

Tags: c, file, load, structure

I'm trying to learn to use structure. load and read a file into struct c, print the file!

I'm trying to read line by line! and print name and last name of each line!

.....

```
int memmove(struct students*s, char line){

int count;  /* The current number of entries in the array */
int remove; /* The entry to remove (index into array, so zero based) */

/* Move the still valid entries one step "down" in the array */

printf("tabort?: ");
        scanf("%s", &line);
    memmove(s + remove, s + (remove + 1),
   sizeof(struct students) * (count - remove - 1));

count--;  /* Now contains one less entry */

}
```

Comment: To start with, don't define variables in header files. To continue, don't use global variables when you don't have to. And to end, you close the file in `load` but accesses the file pointer in `print`.

Comment: I close the file because nothing will change it, I want the file in the consol screen only is why I have struct!, that I want to read the file into an array of struct!

Comment: But if you have closed the file, then _don't continue to read from it_.

Comment: exact!, I close the file and do not want to read from it. that is how I try to do

Comment: But you read from the file in `print` with the `fscanf` Call. That's illegal as the file has been closed. If the `fp` variable was local to the `load` function _as it should be_ then you would have gotten a compiler error there. Now you get a runtime error (i.e. probably a crash).

Comment: ok , how should I read the file from the array in struct , not from the original file!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the  `fscanf` in `print` (where you should only print, not read anything from the file) do a `scanf`-family call in load. Here's an almost complete example on how I would do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH  100
#define MAX_STRUCTS      100

struct analg
{
    char f_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    char l_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
};

/* Load from the named file, into the `analg` array provided, but no more than `max` entries */
/* Returns the number of entries loaded */
int load(char *filename, struct analg *h, int max)
{
    int count = 0;  /* The number of entries we have loaded */

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    char line[MAX_NAME_LENGTH * 2];  /* *2 for first and last name */

    if (fp == NULL)
        return;  /* File could not be opened */

    /* Read all lines, but only as long as we have available entries in the array */
    while (count < max && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        /* Extract the first and last names from the newly read line */
        sscanf(line, "%s %s", h[count].f_name, h[count].l_name);
        count++;  /* Increase counter so we have the current size */
    }

    /* All done loading */
    fclose(fp);

    return count;  /* Return the number of entries we loaded */
}

/* Print from the structure array, there are `count` entries in the array */
void print(struct analg *h, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        /* Print the number and the names */
        /* +1 to the index, because it starts from zero and we want to print it nicely to the user and start from 1 */
        printf("Number %2d: %s %s\n", i + 1, h[i].f_name, h[i].l_name);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct analg h[MAX_STRUCTS];

    int choice;
    int count = 0;  /* Initialize to zero, in case user chooses `print` first */

    do
    {
        printf("choose L or P: ");

        /* Read input from user, as a character, while skipping leading and trailing whitespace */
        scanf(" %c ", &choice);

        switch (tolower(choice))
        {
        case 'l':
            count = load("text.txt", h, MAX_STRUCTS);
            if (count == 0)
                printf("No structures loaded\n");
            break;

        case 'p':
            print(h, count);
            break;

        case 'q':
            /* Do nothing, just catch it for error reporting (below) will work */
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nPlease only use 'p' or 'l', or 'q' for quit\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (tolower(choice) != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```

---

The OP also want to know how to remove an entry once it's been read. The first thing to remember is that the lines are loaded from the file *in order*, so to find a specific line in the array you simply take the line number in the file, and subtract one (as the array indexes are zero-based).

For the actual removal there are a couple of solutions:

1. Keep a boolean flag in the structure, to tell if it's valid or not. When removing an entry, simply set the flag to "false", and ignore all entries where the flag is "false" when printing or saving or other processing.
2. Move the entries above the entry you want to remove down one step. This will overwrite the entry you want to remove, so it no longer exists. It's more work than in the first solution, but will not leave unused entries in the array.

   It's done by using `memmove`:

   ```
   int count;  /* The current number of entries in the array */
   int remove; /* The entry to remove (index into array, so zero based) */

   /* Move the still valid entries one step "down" in the array */
   memmove(h + remove, h + (remove + 1),
          sizeof(struct analg) * (count - remove - 1));

   count--;  /* Now contains one less entry */
   ```

   If you're wondering about the `h + remove` expression, it's called *pointer arithmetic*, and uses the fact that the expression `h[remove]` is the same as `*(h + remove)`, which means that `h + remove` is the same as `&h[remove]`.
3. Instead of using an array, use a linked list, where you append new lines at the end. This is the solution that is the most work, and you also can't easily remove a specific line. However this method makes it very easy to remove (and add) nodes anywhere in the list.

If you want other fields in the structure, like age, then just add that field. You will of course need to modify the parsing of the text file, but if the new field is put at the end of the line in the text file, then just add another format to the `sscanf` call. And when looking for an entry with a specific field set to a specific value, just loop over the array (or list) and compare the field with the wanted value.

Comment: Thank you for helping, thats correct code I think , but do you know ho I can for exemple do a function that can delete the line 2, ex: choose line number to delete : 2. Line is deleted!

Comment: jag såg att du var från Malmö så tänkte skriva på svenska så kan förklara bättre :) , jag tänkte om att kunna ta bort en rad genom att jag väljer rad nummer och tänkte om jag vill till exempel ha deras ålder med hur can jag skriva en array eller variabel som kollar upp åldern?

Comment: @perjohn Jag har uppdaterat (på engelska, så att andra kan förstå. :)) mitt svar.

Comment: thank you for your answering, I trying to make a `switch` and `case`s for the program , I mean like my own program but trying with yours, so I dont get it , do you know how I can for exemple write p to print it or L to load it?

Comment: Det är ett stort problem som jag håller på att lösa:/ men går ej !!

Comment: @perjohn You should be able to use the `switch` statement from your code, but call the function like in my code.

Comment: I dont know what to say, I've tried several times, can you show me how to do?

Comment: @perjohn Ah, I see your problem... In `main` you `scanf` format is _for a string_. You should change the format to `"%c "` to read a character. The trailing space in the format is to discard the newline from the input.

Comment: sorry I dont understand anything , I dont know if I have to use your or my code , because mine is working but not correct , and yours is working correct but I cant make a changes on it ! but thank you very much for helping - @JoachimPileborg

Comment: tack så imla mycket nu fattar jag , tack ska du ha

Comment: @perjohn That's really a new question, and should have been posted as such. But you can't name _your_ function `memmove`. You also should scan into the `remove` or use `line` in the _actual_ `memmove` call, and you have to pass the counter _as a reference_ into the function so you can change it. I recommend you read more about the basic, like functions, function calling, passing arguments as reference etc. This is all very basic stuff.

Comment: ok , jag har nu gjort klart en kod som läser en fil som du visade mig och som skriver ut det, tänkte om det är ok för dig att jag skickar till dig filen och visa dig hur jag tänkte göra samt mina lösningar och om det är ok så kan du förklara för mig vad felet är, så om det är ok skicka mig ditt e-post adress så mejlar jag dig, Mvh

Answer (score 0):

Some changes made to your program to make it work

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct analg {
char f_name[100];
char l_name[100];
};
struct analg h;
FILE *fp;




void load() 
{
fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");

  if(fp == NULL)
  {
   printf("fail");
   return; 
  }

fgets(h.f_name, 100, fp); 
fgets(h.l_name, 100, fp); 


printf("file loaded!\n");
fclose(fp);
return;
}


void print()
{
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s\n",h.f_name,h.l_name);
    printf ("%s\n",h.f_name);
    printf ("%s\n",h.l_name);
return;
}


int main ()
{
char choice;
do{ 
printf("choose L or P: ");
scanf("%c", &choice);
switch(choice)
 {
  case 'l': 
    load();
    printf("\n[l]oad - [p]rint\n");
    break;
  case 'p': 
    print();
    printf("\n[l]oad - [p]rint\n");
    break;    

  default:        
    break;
 }
 }  
 while(choice!='q');

 return 0;
}
```